# Relationship between tcp state TIME_WAIT & HTTP keep-alive

Tags: http, tcp, keepalive, time-wait

What is the relationship between keep-alive on a HTTP request and a tcp socket in TIME_WAIT - should they be correlated?

Furthermore, should system and web server settings be aligned e.g. `server.max-keep-alive-idle = 60`? According to [How to reduce number of sockets in TIME_WAIT?](https://serverfault.com/a/212127/69848) in Linux the TIME_WAIT state is hardcoded at 60 seconds (at least for Ubuntu/Debain values of Linux).

In lighttpd the default value `server.max-keep-alive-idle = 5` and they recommend even lower for high load. It seems a waste to close a http request after 5 seconds if the tcp socket is available - assuming of course that the setting `net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1` does what it says on the tin.

This related question - [How does tcp keep a connection alive? [closed]](https://serverfault.com/questions/312548/how-does-tcp-keep-a-connection-alive) touches on the issue but doesn't fully answer it for me.

Comment: TCP is layer 4, HTTP is layer 7. There's no relationship except if you mean HTTP/1.1 persistent connections instead of HTTP Keep-Alive (which is used for HTTP/1.0).

Comment: I wasn't aware that there was much different between 1.0 and 1.1 - other than it's default in 1.1 - http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html

Comment: Just to mention I've since found a great explaination at http://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2014-tcp-time-wait-state-linux.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TCP is layer 4, HTTP layer 7.

In HTTP 1.0, HTTP Keep-Alive is used at layer 7 to simulate persistent connections using `Connection` header.

In HTTP 1.1, connections are assumed persistent by default and then rely on TCP only to do that job. Requests can be pipelined in the same TCP connection, then one side will set `Connection: close` in the last request or response headers, so both side knows that no more HTTP request can be exchanged and the connection will then be closed.

Usually in the case of a web server, the `TIME_WAIT` state will be the state after which, once decided to actively close the connection, it received client's `FIN` packet and is sending the last `ACK` back in the four-way tear-down. After this, it waits for `2 * MSL` : it's a way to be sure that the connection is closed. That's where the `60s` compiled in the kernel comes from. In this way we are sure that we won't receive in a new connection, using the same 4 tuple, packets out of sequence arising from the previous connection.

**You don't want to change it**.

In the other side `server.max-keep-alive-idle` is the timeout after which an `ESTABLISHED` connection will be considered idle if no HTTP request comes in and will be actively closed by the web server. When this decision is made, as you  understand now, the TCP tear-down will take place.

Be very careful with `tcp_tw_recycle`, if your visitors come from behind a wide NATed network then it could lead to  multiple TCP connections with the same 4 tuple taking place with out of order timestamps resulting in silently dropping client connections attempts on the server side.

So the best option is to adjust the parameter you saw in lighttpd. System-wide, you can safely lower `FIN_WAIT2` state and raise buckets for sockets in `TIME_WAIT` state  with `net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout` and `net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets`.

Comment: I thought that it was tcp_tw_recycle that carried the NAT warning - or is it both? http://www.stolk.org/debian/timewait.html

Comment: @aland Yes it is, was editing :) . The other one, `tcp_tw_reuse` will have no effect on incoming connections and takes place for new outgoing connections.

Comment: Ah, if reuse is only for outgoing then it's not very useful for a webserver I think

Comment: @aland Depends what you do with it, for example if you use it as a reverse proxy it can be useful.